# Detecting Cases using SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-sensitive

I'm trying to use a SQL command that will look through a block of text and determine if it has 3 consecutive uppercase letters in it. Is there a way of doing this? Or even simpler, is there a way that SQL can detect case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function you can use

```
create function ThreeUpperInARow(@s varchar(max)) returns bit
begin
  declare @Rows int

  ;with cte as
  (
    select left(@s, 3) as Part,
           stuff(@s, 1, 1, '') as Rest
    union all
    select left(Rest, 3) as Part,
           stuff(Rest, 1, 1, '') as Rest
    from cte
    where len(Rest) >= 3
  )
  select @Rows = count(*)
  from cte
  where upper(Part) = Part COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

  return case @Rows when 0
           then 0
           else 1
         end
end
```

Usage:

```
declare @T table(ID int identity, Txt varchar(max))
insert into @T
select 'aaaAFAaaaBB' union all
select 'aaaAAaaaBB'

select T.ID,
       T.Txt,
       dbo.ThreeUpperInARow(T.Txt) as Upp
from @T as T
```

Result:

```
ID          Txt             Upp
----------- --------------- -----
1           aaaAFAaaaBB     1
2           aaaAAaaaBB      0
```

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** Question was originally tagged `mysql` and this would've worked.  It's been re-tagged as `sql-server` and this isn't valid for MS SQL Server.

You could use a `REGEXP`

```
SELECT columnname REGEXP '[A-Z]{3}' FROM table;
```

Returns 1 where `columnname` matches.

Comment: SELECT column REGEXP '[A-Z]{4}'
FROM table.column
WHERE LST.column REGEXP '[A-Z]{4}'

Does this make sense? I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: You're selecting `FROM table.column`. You only want `FROM table`. The WHERE clause is kind of unnecessary.

Comment: @Aeonstrife You might want `SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[A-Z]{4}' = 1;` This returns the full text of matching rows in `column`

Comment: 'SELECT column REGEXP '[A-Z]{3}'
FROM table'

isn't working either. It still says there's a syntax error near [A-Z]{3}

Comment: OK that makes more sense to me. However, now the error is:

_An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'._

Comment: @Aeonstrife Are you passing the whole query in enclosed in single-quotes as in your comment? If so, then it would break at the first regexp single-quote.  `SELECT column REGEXP '[A-Z]{3}' FROM table;` should work.

Comment: No that was just my attempt at formatting it for the comments. There are no single quotes around my queries

Comment: @Aeonstrife this is tagged mysql, but that error message only turns up MS SQL Server results for me.  Are you on SQL Server? My syntax was for mysql.

Comment: Yes I'm on an SQL server. Sorry I guess I should have mentioned that. I'm a little new at this

Comment: @Aeonstrife I don't think there's built-in support for regex in SQL Server.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635150/how-do-i-select-a-regex-match-from-a-text-varchar-in-ms-sql I don't think I can assist further.

Comment: Funny, people keep upvoting my answer even though it's totally invalid for the question since retagged from MySQL to SQL Server.

Comment: Totally invalid is a bit harsh. RegExp is what should be used for this so in SQLServer you need to install a .NET assembly that provides the RegExp functionality. Something like this might work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Michael's answer: you can do a case sensitive comparison using this construct:

```
SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC';  /*false*/

SELECT 'aBc' LIKE BINARY 'aBc'; /*true*/
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html
and: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully compared uppercase by casting varchars as varbinary, since uppercase and lowercase compare as equal in SQL

SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,3) as varbinary) = CAST(SUBSTRING(UPPER(ColumnName), 1,3) as varbinary)

One problem with this is that if you have a name like O'Reilly, it will return true.